# php combines array values in main array

Tags: php, arrays

I have total 3 array

First array contains list of titles
Second array contains list of description
third array contains images

I have already combine 1st and 2nd array as a key of first array and value of second array and I also combine 1st and 3rd array as key of 1st and value of 3rd.

Following is my arrays

1 )

```
Array
(
    [First] => FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
    [Second] => ssss
    [0] => Array
        (
            [First] => eae2d7b3f20250def1892bae1abaf07f.png
            [Second] => ea7ca514d1ef580f85fb42c7cb425462.png
        )

)
```

I want output like

Array

```
(
    [First] => FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
    [Second] => ssss
    [First] => eae2d7b3f20250def1892bae1abaf07f.png
    [Second] => ea7ca514d1ef580f85fb42c7cb425462.png
)
```

Code

```
foreach ($images as $key => $value) {
            $values['image']= $value;
        }


$data = array_combine($_POST['title'], $images);


 $mainArray = array_combine($_POST['title'], $_POST['Description']);


array_push($mainArray,$data);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($mainArray);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: show us the code wich you have written

Comment: Specifically show us the arrays before you merged them.

Comment: First, Second same key should not be used twice in an array if we would like to do then value should be [First] => array(value1,value2)

Comment: You can't have keys with the same name.

Comment: give me example with code please

Comment: It's not possible to have same key in an array.

Answer (score 0):

The code below should produce the format the array as required above, although it is not the most elegant way to flatten an array. It may be worthwhile looking at previous questions like [How to Flatten a Multidimensional Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array/1320259)

```
$newArr = array();
foreach ( $mainArray as $key => $val ) {
    if ( is_array( $val ) ) {
        foreach ( $val as $key2 => $val2 ) {
            $newArr[$key2] = $val2;
        }
    } else {
        $newArr[$key] = $val;
    } 
}
```